# How to make the information extracted from XML be available outside current context?

Tags: c#, xml

I have this method that reads a particular .xml file and stores some information inside two strings.

However i cannot access those strings from outside that method.

Inside button1_Click event, both strings cannot be accessed (does not exist in the current context error)

How to solve this? Here's the code:

```
private void checkXML(string _title)
    {
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\Directory\test.xml"))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.IsStartElement())
                {
                    switch (reader.Name)
                    {
                        case "myElement":
                            string title = reader["title"];
                            if (title == _title)
                            {
                                string string1 = (reader["publisher"]);
                                string string2 = (reader["author"]);
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkXML("The Cookbook");
        MessageBox.Show(string1); //error: "The name 'string1' does not exist in the current context"
        MessageBox.Show(string2); //error: "The name 'string2' does not exist in the current context"
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: make string1 and string 2 class fields to make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the two variables as class fields:

```
public class SomeClass : SomeBaseClass
{

 string string1="";
 string string2 ="";  // defined on class level

private void checkXML(string _title)
    {
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\Directory\test.xml"))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.IsStartElement())
                {
                    switch (reader.Name)
                    {
                        case "myElement":
                            string title = reader["title"];
                            if (title == _title)
                            {
                                string1 = (reader["publisher"]);
                                string2 = (reader["author"]); // set values here
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkXML("The Cookbook");
        MessageBox.Show(string1); //Now aviable here"
        MessageBox.Show(string2); //Available here"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. Create new Type for result and return that type from the method with the values filled. use that values in the calling method.

```
class XmlResult
{
    public string string1 {get; set;}
    public string string2 {get; set;}
}

private XmlResult checkXML(string _title)
{
    var result = new XmlResult();
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\Directory\test.xml"))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.IsStartElement())
            {
                switch (reader.Name)
                {
                    case "myElement":
                        string title = reader["title"];
                        if (title == _title)
                        {
                            result.string1 = (reader["publisher"]);
                            result.string2 = (reader["author"]);
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var result = checkXML("The Cookbook");
    MessageBox.Show(result.string1); //error: "The name 'string1' does not exist in the current context"
    MessageBox.Show(result.string2); //error: "The name 'string2' does not exist in the current context"
}
```